# Placing elements next to each other without wrapper div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm currently styling a WordPress site's contact form. The desired result should look something like this:

[image: Four text input fields next to a large text area]

Normally, this could be easily achieved with a wrapper div around the text fields. Since this is WordPress, I can't do this without digging into the plugin (which is the last thing I want to do). The HTML WordPress produces looks like this:

```
<form ...>
  <p class="..." data-id="name" data-type="input">
    <label ...>Naam Achternaam</label>
    <input type="text" ...>
  </p>
  <p class="..." data-id="company" data-type="input">
    <label ...>Bedrijf</label>
    <input type="text" ...>
  </p>
  <p class="..." data-id="email" data-type="input">
    <label ...>E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" ...>
  </p>
  <p class="..." data-id="phone" data-type="input">
    <label ...>Telefoonnummer</label>
    <input type="text" ...>
  </p>
  <p class="..." data-id="message" data-type="text">
    <label ...>Vragen / opmerkingen</label>
    <textarea ...></textarea>
  </p>
  ...
</form>
```

which currently looks like this:

[image: Four text fields and a text area placed next to each other, 2 by 2]

Is it possible to achieve what I'm after with this HTML structure or do I need to find a way to accommodate a wrapper div?

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: @RobertWilliams Sure thing. Give me a sec.

Comment: @RobertWilliams https://jsfiddle.net/gbrmqswf/

Comment: Did @ovokuro's answer worked for you?

Comment: @RobertWilliams It works, but in an ideal world, you wouldn't want to resort to `position: absolute`. If that is the only possibility, it'll have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `position: absolute` on the last `p`... not the nicest solution but a possible workaround without changing the `HTML`

```css
form {
  background: #00CDD4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

form p {
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 45%;
}

form p label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  opacity: .87;
}

form p input {
  border: none;
  padding: 1em;
}

form p:last-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

form p:last-of-type textarea {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <p class="..." data-id="name" data-type="input">
    <label ...>Naam Achternaam</label>
    <input type="text" ...>
  </p>
  <p class="..." data-id="company" data-type="input">
    <label ...>Bedrijf</label>
    <input type="text" ...>
  </p>
  <p class="..." data-id="email" data-type="input">
    <label ...>E-mail</label>
    <input type="email" ...>
  </p>
  <p class="..." data-id="phone" data-type="input">
    <label ...>Telefoonnummer</label>
    <input type="text" ...>
  </p>
  <p class="..." data-id="message" data-type="text">
    <label ...>Vragen / opmerkingen</label>
    <textarea ...></textarea>
  </p>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess there isn't really an alternative to absolute.

Answer (score 1):

I tried alot but following your requirements it seems only possible through position absolute. Just for fun I tried to make without display: flex;

```css
body {
  background-color: #2dccd3;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

form.contact{
  position: relative;
}

p.contact-field {
  width: 45%;
}

p.contact-field input{
  width: 100%;
}

input, label {
    display:block;
}

p.contact-field:last-child{
  margin: 0px;
}

.contact-field:last-child{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 89%;
}

textarea#message{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<form class="contact">
  <p class="contact-field" data-id="name" data-type="input">
    <label for="name">Naam Achternaam</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name">
  </p>
  <p class="contact-field" data-id="company" data-type="input">
    <label for="company">Bedrijf</label>
    <input id="company" type="text" name="company">
  </p>
  <p class="contact-field" data-id="email" data-type="input">
    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email">
  </p>
  <p class="contact-field" data-id="phone" data-type="input">
    <label for="phone">Telefoonnummer</label>
    <input id="phone" type="text" name="phone">
  </p>
  
  <p class="contact-field" data-id="message" data-type="text">
    <label for="message">Vragen / opmerkingen</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
  </p>
</form>
```